# How do I check that multiple keys are in a dict in a single pass?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to do something like:

```
foo = {
    'foo': 1,
    'zip': 2,
    'zam': 3,
    'bar': 4
}

if ("foo", "bar") in foo:
    #do stuff
```

How do I check whether both `foo` and `bar` are in dict `foo`?

Answer (score 501, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
>>> if all(k in foo for k in ("foo","bar")):
...     print "They're there!"
...
They're there!
```

Comment: +1, I like this better than Greg's answer because it's more concise AND faster (no building of irrelevant temporary list, AND full exploitation of short-circuiting).

Comment: I love all() and any(). They make so many algorithms so much cleaner.

Comment: I ultimately ended up using this solution.  It seemed the best for larger datasets. When checking for say 25 or 30 keys.

Comment: It's a good solution thanks to short-circuiting, especially if the test fails more often than not; unless you can create the set of keys of interest just once and check it many times, in which case `set` is superior. As usual... measure it!-)

Comment: I use this whenever it looks nicer than the "normal" way, with all the and's or the or's... it's also nice 'cause you can use either "all" or "any"... in addition you can either have "k in foo" or "k not in foo" depending on the test you are trying to perform

Comment: checkout @claytonk's solution, more concise and a 60% performance boost

Comment: With Python 3, we retain short-circuiting if we use `map()`, as in: `all(map(foo.has_key, ("foo","bar")))`.

Answer (score 162):

```
if {"foo", "bar"} <= myDict.keys(): ...
```

If you're still on Python 2, you can do

```
if {"foo", "bar"} <= myDict.viewkeys(): ...
```

If you're still on a *really* old Python <= 2.6, you can call `set` on the dict, but it'll iterate over the whole dict to build the set, and that's slow:

```
if set(("foo", "bar")) <= set(myDict): ...
```

Comment: looks good! The only thing I don't like is that you have to create temporary sets, but it's very compact. So I must say... nice use of sets!

Comment: In python 3 you can say `set(("foo","bar")) <= myDict.keys()` which avoids the temporary set, so is much faster. For my testing it is about the same speed as using all when the query was 10 items. It gets slower as the query gets bigger though.

Comment: I've posted some of my tests as an answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285911/python-how-do-i-check-that-multiple-keys-are-in-a-dict-in-one-go/1552005#1552005

Comment: `if {'foo', 'bar'} <= set(myDict): ...`

Comment: For anyone wondering why this works: the operator <= is the same as use .set issubset() method: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset

Comment: {'foo','bar'} <= myDict.keys()

Comment: @BorisRaicheff please clarify how is this better?

Answer (score 47):

### Simple benchmarking rig for 3 of the alternatives.

Put in your own values for D and Q

```
>>> from timeit import Timer
>>> setup='''from random import randint as R;d=dict((str(R(0,1000000)),R(0,1000000)) for i in range(D));q=dict((str(R(0,1000000)),R(0,1000000)) for i in range(Q));print("looking for %s items in %s"%(len(q),len(d)))'''

>>> Timer('set(q) <= set(d)','D=1000000;Q=100;'+setup).timeit(1)
looking for 100 items in 632499
0.28672504425048828

#This one only works for Python3
>>> Timer('set(q) <= d.keys()','D=1000000;Q=100;'+setup).timeit(1)
looking for 100 items in 632084
2.5987625122070312e-05

>>> Timer('all(k in d for k in q)','D=1000000;Q=100;'+setup).timeit(1)
looking for 100 items in 632219
1.1920928955078125e-05
```

Comment: Python 2.7 has `d.viewkeys()` to make `set(q) <= d.viewkeys()`.

Comment: `Python 2.7.5` has `d.keys()` method too.

Comment: @IvanKharlamov, but in Python2, it doesn't return an object that is compatible with `set(q) <= ...`

Comment: My bad, you're absolutely spot on: it returns `TypeError: can only compare to a set`. Sorry! :))

Comment: For Python 2 switch the order: `d.viewkeys() >= set(q)`. I came here trying to find out why the order matters!

Answer (score 43):

You don't have to wrap the left side in a set. You can just do this:

```py
if {'foo', 'bar'} <= set(some_dict):
    pass
```

This also performs better than the `all(k in d...)` solution.

Comment: This also performs better than the all(k in d...) solution. I suggested this as an edit, but it was rejected on grounds it was [better to add a comment](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6905833). So here's me doing just that

Comment: @miraculixx It's not better to add a comment.  It's better to edit relevant information into an answer and delete the comments.

Comment: @endolith I agree, some people obviously don't as you can see in the rejected edit that I did in the first place. Anyway that's a discussion for meta not for here.

Comment: Can someone explain this please?  I've gathered that {} creates a set, but how is the less-than-or-equal operator working here?

Comment: @Locane The <= operator tests if the first set is a subset of the second set. You could also do {'foo', 'bar'}.issubset(somedict). The documentation for set methodology can be found here:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html

Answer (score 28):

Using **[sets](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)**:

```
if set(("foo", "bar")).issubset(foo):
    #do stuff
```

Alternatively:

```
if set(("foo", "bar")) <= set(foo):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: set(d) as I used in my answer is just like set(d.keys()) but faster, shorter, and I would say stylistically preferable.

Comment: `set(d)` is the same as `set(d.keys())` ( without the intermediate list that `d.keys()` constructs )

Answer (score 24):

This should work:

```
if all(key in foo for key in ["foo","bar"]):
    # do stuff
    pass
```

---

**Hint:**

Using square brackets inside `all()` to make a list comprehension:

```
if all([key in foo for key in ["foo","bar"]]):
```

Is not only unnecessary, but it is positively harmful, as they impede the normal short-circuiting behavior of `all()`.

Answer (score 13):

I think this is the smartest and most Pythonic.

```
{'key1','key2'} <= my_dict.keys()
```

Comment: There is no explanation of how or why this works. The operator needs to be explained as well.

Answer (score 12):

While I like Alex Martelli's answer, it doesn't seem Pythonic to me.  That is, I thought an important part of being Pythonic is to be easily understandable.  With that goal, `<=` isn't easy to understand.

While it's more characters, using `issubset()` as suggested by Karl Voigtland's answer is more understandable.  Since that method can use a dictionary as an argument, a short, understandable solution is:

```py
foo = {'foo': 1, 'zip': 2, 'zam': 3, 'bar': 4}

if set(('foo', 'bar')).issubset(foo):
    #do stuff
```

I'd like to use `{'foo', 'bar'}` in place of `set(('foo', 'bar'))`, because it's shorter.  However, it's not that understandable and I think the braces are too easily confused as being a dictionary.

Comment: I think it's understandable once you understand what it means.

Comment: It's [in the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.issubset) as a synonym for `.issubset()`. I think being in Python documentation makes it Pythonic by default.

Comment: My preferred one is: `if {'foo', 'bar'}.issubset(foo):`

Answer (score 10):

check for existence of all keys in a dict:

```
{'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3'} <= set(my_dict)
```

check for existence of one or more keys in a dict:

```
{'key_1', 'key_2', 'key_3'} & set(my_dict)
```

Answer (score 4):

Alex Martelli's solution `set(queries) <= set(my_dict)` is the shortest code but may not be the fastest. Assume Q = len(queries) and D = len(my_dict).

This takes O(Q) + O(D) to make the two sets, and then (one hopes!) only O(min(Q,D)) to do the subset test -- assuming of course that Python set look-up is O(1) -- this is worst case (when the answer is True).

The generator solution of hughdbrown (et al?) `all(k in my_dict for k in queries)` is worst-case O(Q).

Complicating factors:
(1) the loops in the set-based gadget are all done at C-speed whereas the any-based gadget is looping over bytecode.
(2) The caller of the any-based gadget may be able to use any knowledge of probability of failure to order the query items accordingly whereas the set-based gadget allows no such control.

As always, if speed is important, benchmarking under operational conditions is a good idea.

Comment: The generator was faster for all the cases I tried. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285911/python-how-do-i-check-that-multiple-keys-are-in-a-dict-in-one-go/1552005#1552005

Answer (score 3):

You can use [.issubset()](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/issubset.html) as well

```
>>> {"key1", "key2"}.issubset({"key1":1, "key2":2, "key3": 3})
True
>>> {"key4", "key2"}.issubset({"key1":1, "key2":2, "key3": 3})
False
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

short and sweet

`{"key1", "key2"} <= {*dict_name}`

Comment: Your answer seems to be the same as many other answers

Answer (score 1):

How about using lambda?

```
 if reduce( (lambda x, y: x and foo.has_key(y) ), [ True, "foo", "bar"] ): # do stuff
```

Comment: This answer is the only functionally-correct one that will work on Python 1.5 with a simple change (s/True/1/) ... but it's got nothing else going for it. AND the True thingy would be better as the optional initializer arg rather than crammed into the front of the sequence arg.

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to:

- also get the values for the keys
- check more than one dictonary

then:

```
from operator import itemgetter
foo = {'foo':1,'zip':2,'zam':3,'bar':4}
keys = ("foo","bar") 
getter = itemgetter(*keys) # returns all values
try:
    values = getter(foo)
except KeyError:
    # not both keys exist
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

Not to suggest that this isn't something that you haven't thought of, but I find that the simplest thing is usually the best:

```
if ("foo" in foo) and ("bar" in foo):
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> if 'foo' in foo and 'bar' in foo:
...     print 'yes'
... 
yes
```

Jason, () aren't necessary in Python.

Comment: Still they might be good style... without them, my C++-addled brain always wonders if it's going to be interpreted as "if 'foo in (foo and 'bar') in foo:"

Comment: I understand that they aren't necessary.  I just feel that they add clarity in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Just my take on this, there are two methods that are easy to understand of all the given options. So my main criteria is have very readable code, not exceptionally fast code. To keep code understandable, i prefer to given possibilities:

- var <= var2.keys()
- var.issubset(var2)

The fact that "var <= var2.keys()" executes faster in my testing below, i prefer this one.

```
import timeit

timeit.timeit('var <= var2.keys()', setup='var={"managed_ip", "hostname", "fqdn"}; var2= {"zone": "test-domain1.var23.com", "hostname": "bakje", "api_client_ip": "127.0.0.1", "request_data": "", "request_method": "GET", "request_url": "hvar2p://127.0.0.1:5000/test-domain1.var23.com/bakje", "utc_datetime": "04-Apr-2019 07:01:10", "fqdn": "bakje.test-domain1.var23.com"}; var={"managed_ip", "hostname", "fqdn"}')
0.1745898080000643

timeit.timeit('var.issubset(var2)', setup='var={"managed_ip", "hostname", "fqdn"}; var2= {"zone": "test-domain1.var23.com", "hostname": "bakje", "api_client_ip": "127.0.0.1", "request_data": "", "request_method": "GET", "request_url": "hvar2p://127.0.0.1:5000/test-domain1.var23.com/bakje", "utc_datetime": "04-Apr-2019 07:01:10", "fqdn": "bakje.test-domain1.var23.com"}; var={"managed_ip", "hostname", "fqdn"};')
0.2644960229999924
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of determining whether only some keys match, this works:

```
any_keys_i_seek = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

if set(my_dict).intersection(any_keys_i_seek):
    # code_here
    pass
```

Yet another option to find if only some keys match:

```
any_keys_i_seek = ["key1", "key2", "key3"]

if any_keys_i_seek & my_dict.keys():
    # code_here
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option for detecting whether all keys are in a dict:

```
dict_to_test = { ... }  # dict
keys_sought = { "key_sought_1", "key_sought_2", "key_sought_3" }  # set

if keys_sought & dict_to_test.keys() == keys_sought: 
    # True -- dict_to_test contains all keys in keys_sought
    # code_here
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative solution in case you want to get the items that didn't match...

```
not_existing_keys = [item for item in ["foo","bar"] if item not in foo]
if not_existing_keys:
  log.error('These items are missing', not_existing_keys)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
my_dict = {
    'name': 'Askavy',
    'country': 'India',
    'age': 30
}

if set(('name', 'country','age')).issubset(my_dict.keys()):
     print("All keys are present in the dictionary") 
else: 
    print("All keys are not present in  the dictionary")
```

Comment: Please, add a brief explanation of how/why it solves the problem.

Comment: This solution was already given in the most upvoted answers.

Answer (score 0):

To me, simple and easy with None key in the middle with `pydash` [ref](https://pydash.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

```
import pydash as _
_.get(d, 'key1.key2.key3.whatevermaybeNone.inthemiddle', default=None) )
```

Answer (score 0):

If the reason you are checking for the keys is to make sure you can access them, one option is to not check - just try to access them and then do the needful if necessary.

```
foo = {
    'bar': 4
}

try:
    alpha = foo['bar']
    beta = foo['leroy_jenkins']
except KeyError:
    pass # Or some other thing if you don't have the keys you expected.
```

Answer (score -4):

```
>>> ok
{'five': '5', 'two': '2', 'one': '1'}

>>> if ('two' and 'one' and 'five') in ok:
...   print "cool"
... 
cool
```

This seems to work

Comment: This is clever and I was convinced it didn't work until I tried it myself.  I suspected the `()` would be evaluated first and result in `True`, which would then check if `True in ok`.  How does this actually work?!

Comment: ('two' and 'one' and 'five') returns 'five', so it actually checks only  if 'five' is on the dict