# Dict has key from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

How can I determine if any of the list elements are a key to a dict?
The straight forward way is,

```
for i in myList:
   if i in myDict:
      return True
return False
```

but is there a faster / more concise way?

Comment: @Dario: it could be boo, but I guess the answers will be the same anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about python, an alternate method of doing this would be:

```
return len([x for x in myList if x in myDict]) > 0
```

Comment: Two problems: this unnecessarily builds a list and looks for all occurrences without short-circuiting.

Answer (score 20):

```
#!python
any(x in MyDict for x in MyList)
set(MyList).intersection(MyDict)
```

Comment: +1 for clarity, efficiency (of the first version only!), and simplicity.

Comment: btw, 'set' version is faster than 'any' version if key from `MyDict' is not at the beginning of `MyList` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737778/dict-has-key-from-list/1737862#1737862

Answer (score 6):

In addition to `any(item in my_dict for item in my_list)` from [@Ronny's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737778/dict-has-key-from-list/1737790#1737790):

```
any(map(my_dict.__contains__, my_list)) # Python 3.x
```

Or:

```
from itertools import imap
any(imap(my_dict.__contains__, my_list)) # Python 2.x
```

### Measure relative performance

Cases to consider:

1. Item from the start of list is in in dictionary.
2. Item from the end of list is in dictionary.
3. No items from the list are in dictionary.

Functions to compare (see [main.py](http://gist.github.com/235395)):

```
def mgag_loop(myDict, myList):
    for i in myList:
        if i in myDict:
            return True
    return False

def ronny_any(myDict, myList):
    return any(x in myDict for x in myList)

def ronny_set(myDict, myList):
    return set(myDict) & set(myList)

def pablo_len(myDict, myList):
    return len([x for x in myList if x in myDict]) > 0

def jfs_map(my_dict, my_list):
    return any(map(my_dict.__contains__, my_list))

def jfs_imap(my_dict, my_list):
    return any(imap(my_dict.__contains__, my_list))
```

Results: *`mgag_loop()` is the fastest in all cases.*

#### 1. Item from the start of list is in in dictionary.

```
def args_key_at_start(n):
    'Make args for comparison functions "key at start" case.'
    d, lst = args_no_key(n)
    lst.insert(0, n//2)
    assert (n//2) in d and lst[0] == (n//2)
    return (d, lst)
```

[image: key at start]

#### 2. Item from the end of list is in dictionary.

```
def args_key_at_end(n):
    'Make args for comparison functions "key at end" case.'
    d, lst = args_no_key(n)
    lst.append(n//2)
    assert (n//2) in d and lst[-1] == (n//2)
    return (d, lst)
```

[image: key at end]

#### 3. No items from the list are in dictionary.

```
def args_no_key(n):
    'Make args for comparison functions "no key" case.'
    d = dict.fromkeys(xrange(n))
    lst = range(n, 2*n+1)
    assert not any(x in d for x in lst)
    return (d, lst)
```

[image: no key]

#### How to reproduce

Download [main.py](http://gist.github.com/235395), [make-figures.py](http://gist.github.com/235404), run `python main.py` (`numpy`, `matplotlib` should be installed to create plots).

To change maximum size of input list, number of points to plot supply `--maxn`, `--npoints` correspondingly. Example:

```
$ python main.py --maxn 65536 --npoints 16
```

Comment: The key advantage of `any` is that it short-circuits, and `any(map(...` loses that key advantage!

Comment: Brilliant. I don't know python very well and learned a lot today by reading all the answer. Your summary is awesome. You should be awarded with the answer! :-)

Comment: OMG.  I will go back and test tomorrow night.

Comment: @Alex: You're right. I've clarified that 'map' variant is suitable for Python 3.x

Comment: @mgag: Beware that micro-benchmarks do not matter much. Always measure performance of *your* code *before* applying any optimizations.

Comment: if it helps, the list always has between 1-4 elements, and the dict has ~100-150 elements.

Comment: I need to work with python 2.5+.  Speed is a issue for customer of my code - but thru other optimizations I am in the good now. But I will go back and test given result from Alex - I may have abandoned my approach too soon and not gone back and tested while I did other optimizations....

Comment: I tested between the two, specifically, 
 len([x for x in nodeList if x in removeNode]) > 0
vs
 def mgag_loop(myDict, myList):
    for i in myList:
        if i in myDict:
            return True
    return False

And the results are nearly identical for three runs (~80sec for each run), within 1%. The second option was always faster, but the margin is small.

Comment: i just noticed the set version is not equivalent to mine

Comment: @Ronny could you elaborate? Are you talking about `ronny_set()`? It is the same as yours at the time of the answer.

Comment: indeed, i completely forgot and missed the history

Answer (score 1):

[This was a popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285911/python-how-do-i-check-that-multiple-keys-are-in-a-dict-in-one-go/1285920#1285920) to a related question:

```
>>> if all (k in foo for k in ("foo","bar")):
...     print "They're there!"
...
They're there!
```

You can adapt it to check if any appears in the dictionary:

```
>>> if any(k in myDict for k in ("foo","bar")):
...     print "Found one!"
...
Found one!
```

You can check against a list of keys:

```
>>> if any(k in myDict for k in myList):
...     print "Found one!"
...
Found one!
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all so much.  I tested the performance of all the answers and the fastest was

```
return len([x for x in myList if x in myDict]) > 0
```

but I didn't try the "set" answer because I didn't see how to turn it into one line.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

The any() solution was much more elegant.

Comment: FYI, You'll want to use the checkmark to denote your accepted answer rather than post another answer like this.

Comment: I can't see how `len()` can be faster. What input have you used? I've measured performance for all answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1737778/dict-has-key-from-list/1737862#1737862