# Finding string in Python Object with multiple OR conditions

Tags: python, operators

I am trying to control for many variables in an object. To do so I am looking to see if certain words exist in the object:

```
jobs = csv.DictReader(open("jobsFile.csv", "rb"))
jobsWithRoles = []

for i in jobs:
     if "Clerk" or "Stock" or "Sales" in jobs['Roles']:
          i["RoleNum"] = 1
          jobsWithRoles.append(i)
elif "Janitor" or "President" or "Driver" in jobs["Roles"]:
         i["RoleNum"] = 2
         jobsWithRoles.append(i)
else:
         i["RoleNum"] = 5
         jobsWithRoles.append(i)
```

The problem is that everything is getting assigned "1" regardless if they strings exist or not.

Comment: Do you need to test if the current row `i` has a certain set of roles? You are testing against the `jobs` dict reader here, which doesn't support `in` membership testing anyway.

Comment: Are `elif` and `else` well intended? Are you `else`ing the `for`?

Comment: I dont know where the response when (user deleted) but he was right.

`if any(x in i['Roles'] for x in ("Clerk", "Stock", "Sales")):`

Comment: @tgunn - I deleted my post because there was a ton of confusion as to what the OP wanted and I (at the time) didn't have enough free time to work it out.  Now I wish I would have just stuck to my guns. :(

Comment: @iCodez, bummer man - I read your post and was implementing it - when I came back it was gone....

Big thanks regardless - I'll try to be clearer in the future

Comment: @iCodez but you can always undelete it, and I think it's appropriate

Comment: @alko - Well, I originally didn't see a need since the OP answered his own question with my answer (and gave proper citing).  But if you guys want it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, your code is being evaluated like this:

```
if ("Clerk") or ("Stock") or ("Sales" in jobs['Roles']):
```

Furthermore, since non-empty strings evaluate to `True` in Python, your if-statement will *always* pass because it is evaluating non-empty strings.

What I think you meant to do was this:

```
# Notice how I replaced `jobs['Roles']` with `i['Roles']`
if "Clerk" in i['Roles'] or "Stock" in i['Roles'] or "Sales" in i['Roles']:
```

Or, you could do this:

```
if any(x in i['Roles'] for x in ("Clerk", "Stock", "Sales")):
```

which is cleaner.

Comment: I am not certain that this is what the OP wants either. I suspect it should be `i['Roles'] in ("Clerk", "Stock", "Sales")` instead. Looping over all of `jobs` *per row iteration* won't work anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I don't think so. I think he is looking for job "tiers", grouping "X clerk", "Y clerk", and "Z clerk" together. And on the other hand "President", "General President" and "Vice President". But I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, I assume that your indentation is bad and you meant `elif` and `else` to correspond to `if`.

The first condition in your `if` is `"Clerk"` and it always evaluates to `True`, like all strings do.
Check this out:

```
>>> d = dict()
>>> if "string" or "NOT THERE!" in d:
...     print("Hello world!")
... 
Hello world!
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285911/python-how-do-i-check-that-multiple-keys-are-in-a-dict-in-one-go) may be a solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the first condition you have always will be evaluate as True.

```
if "Clerk" or "Stock" or "Sales" in jobs['Roles']
```

So, you are saying: if "Clerk" is true or "Stock" is true, etc... .

And Python evaluates any string different than "" as true.

I recommend you use a function like:

```
def search_in_jobs(words, jobs):
    for w in words:
        if w in jobs: return True
    return False
```

then rewrite the condition:

```
if search_in_jobs(["Clerk", "Stock", "Sales"], jobs)
```