# How to check if a dictionary contains multiple elements?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a two-dimensional array, where each cell contains a dictionary that is randomly populated with a human, mosquito(es), or both. This looks like this:

```
{'human': Human instance, 'mosquitoes': [Mosquito instance]}
```

I loop through the two-dimensional array, and for every cell I check:

```
for row in my_array:
    for cell in row:
        if cell['human']:
            do this
        elif cell['mosquitoes']:
            do this
        elif cell[both]:
            do this
```

I've already tried the things suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285911/python-how-do-i-check-that-multiple-keys-are-in-a-dict-in-one-go), but I haven't been able to get it to work so far.

Comment: What is an example of how "both" would look like in your dictionary?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: You may want to somehow "keep track" of how many you encounter.  How could you store a value that contains a number of occurrences?

Comment: Not sure if I understood the question, you want a way to test for both (if you have both keys in the dictionary)? If so  `elif cell['human'] and cell['mosquitoes']:` should do the trick.

Comment: @RahulGupta I'm not getting an error, it just isn't working.

Comment: Its because the both check is in the elif so it never runs. make it the first if to check both, then elif check each of the human and mosquitoes

Comment: Can you show more of your code so we can better understand the flow of your logic?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus it says what each cell is in my post.

Comment: @Amos: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus it literally says in my question that each cell is a `dict`, with 'human': `Human` and 'mosquitoes': [`Mosquito`es].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cell[both]` will never run because its the last `elif` check. Make it the first if.

```
if cell['human'] and cell['mosquitoes']:
    do this
elif cell['human']:
    do this
elif cell['mosquitoes]:
    do this
```

Note that if either `human` or `mosquitoes` keys are not present, you might get  `KeyError`. So you might need to use `cell.get(key)` syntax instead of `cell[key]` to cater for such events.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the useful answer and your suggestion of using cell.get(key).

Answer (score 0):

#### Did you consider trying:

```
if cell['mosquitoes'] and cell['human']:
    # your code goes here for this case
elif cell['mosquitoes']:
    # your code goes here for this case
elif cell['human']:
    # your code goes here for this case
```

Comment: Because it doesn't execute the code beneath it. It doesn't enter the elif.